# How to delete an item from array in recursive object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, recursion

Json object

```
page = {
...
  blocks:[
    ...,
    page: {
       blocks:[]
    }
  ]
}
```

It representaion of C# classes:

```
class Page {
    List<Block> blocks;
}
abstract class AbstractBlock{
    ContentType contentType;
}
class PageBlock: AbstractBlock {
    Page page;
}
```

In this object there is an array field `blocks`
I have some stuff that creates html object from json. Some lines from there:

```
var blockSelector = generateBlockSelector(blockJson);
...
appendToPageBlock(blockJson);
setBlockStyles(blockSelector);
```

So I has been generating all I need from Json. But now I have a problem with removing blocks. When users click delete block I should delete it from html and from `blocks`. Now when user clicks delete I can access to `blockJson` and `blockSelector`. Is there is a way to say element delete itself from array, something like this:

```
function removeBlock(blockJson, blockSelector) {
    blockJson.removeItSelf();
    $(blockSelector).remove();
}
```

Comment: *"in recursive object"* - Recursive? As in circular references? Or just child objects of the same structure?

Comment: @nnnnnn The chain page->block->page->block->page->block ... can be infinite, I don't know the right term for this, but I think it seemilar to recursion. The second child objects of the same structure.